# Nothing happen when I set value a child in database Firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a node in database in Firebase but nothing happens.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: (emailTextField.text!), password: (passwordTextField.text!)) { (result, error) in
    if let _eror = error {
        print(_eror.localizedDescription )
    } else {
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").child((result?.user.uid)!).setValue(["username": self.usernameTextField.text!])
    }
}
```

Here is in the console
[image]

When I click 'Sign Up', I find that it's still having a new user created in Firebase.

Comment: In the future, instead of linking to an image of the console, paste the text of the error in your question. Thanks!

Comment: I will notice that, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console output you shared shows the error:

> setValue: or removeValue: at /users/E7... failed permission_denied

Check the rules for your [Firebase project database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/_/rules) and ensure that write access is granted

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == user_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it works. thank you, i forgot modifying the rules :(